# How to work with List.GetRange()

Tags: c#

```
int k=7;
int index1=5;
```

`arrayNames` has 11 values in it.

```
if (k - index1 > 1)
{
   arrayNames1 = arrayNames.GetRange(index1, k);
}
```

But it throws me an error as 
"**Offset and length were out of bounds for the array or count is greater than the number of elements from index to the end of the source collection.**"

Comment: For starters, `7+5` **IS** greater than 11

Comment: I doubt on that.. from 5 to 7 in arrayNames.. I need to get all those values...

Comment: @SRIRAMRAMACHANDRAN Not `from 5 to 7`. It is "7 elements from 5"

Comment: You are trying to get 7 elements starting from index 5 (up to and including index 11 – which does not exist in your array). If you want elements 5 to 7 (inclusive), use `.GetRange(5, 3)` instead.

Answer (score 10):

If you change the `k` from 7 to 6, it will work. This happens because `GetRange`, as it is stated in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/21k0e39c(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Creates a shallow copy of a range of elements in the source

The first parameter you pass in the `GetRange` method is the index it will start the copy and the second parameter the number of elements that will be copied.

Presuming that `arrayNames` contains the following data:

```
0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10
```

If `index = 5` and `count = 7`, it will try to copy the values of the element in the following positions:

```
5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11(?)
```

Since `arrayNames` only goes up to 10 (as it is zero-based), there isn't any element in position 11. Hence you get this error.

Comment: It will only get 7 elements, not 8. Position/Index 11 should be the last in your list. But since arrays are zero-based in C#, index 10 is the last index of an array with 11 items.

Comment: Oops you are correct ! Thank you very much for pointing this out ! I will correct it.

Answer (score 9):

The reason of exception is due to invalid usage of parameters of `GetRange` extension method:

```
public List<T> GetRange(int index, int count);
```

first parameter is the first element's index, whereas the second one is the number of elements you want to receive from first index.
You should you it in this way:

```
var resRange= myArray.ToList().GetRange(firstIndex, lastIndex - firstIndex);
```

Of course the result of `lastIndex - firstIndex` mustn't be more than `myArray.Count()`.

Answer (score 6):

Taken from here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.arraylist.getrange(v=vs.110).aspx

> Parameters index Type: System.Int32 The zero-based ArrayList index at
>   which the range starts. count Type: System.Int32 The number of
>   elements in the range.

You currently try to take 7 elements starting from index 5. Your collection has 11 elements and you are trying to take the 12th one. If you modify your start index to 4 or you take 6 elements with start index 5 everything should work.

You can replace your code with:

```
arrayNames1 = arrayNames.Skip(index1).Take(k).ToArray();
```

Comment: @SRIRAMRAMACHANDRAN the indexes are zero based you are starting from element 5 (6 in the context and you are trying to get 7 elements) 5+7 = 12

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to see that the [`index` parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.arraylist.getrange?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-6.0#parameters) value is retrievable from the already known

`arrayNames.Count()` value / 11

and the

[`count` parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.arraylist.getrange?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-6.0#parameters) value / 7.

Or simply `index` = (or <=) (`arrayNames.Count() - count`)

`GetRange((arrayNames.Count() - count), count)` .

`index` must be less than or equal to `arrayNames.Count() - count`.

In you example it would give:

`GetRange((11-7), 7)` ;

or `GetRange(4, 7)`.

Such that WE MUST derive the `index` value from subtracting the `count` from the `List/ArrayList total value` (or at least make sure the `index` value is `<=` the `List/ArrayList total value minus the count value`).